# Why is weather stack throwing me this error on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I was using the weather stack api (https://weatherstack.com) in my React project. I was making the request to the dates with Axios, the problem comes when I ask for the dates, it returned me a error of 'https_access_restricted'.

The error doesn't make sense because I verify the url and it was good without using the protocol ssl, the api key it was also good and the query too, the curious thing is if I execute that code without React with Nodejs, it works perfectly, but when I implement React it throws that error.

The code (App.js):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
    const [ weather, setWeather ] = useState([]);
    const params = {
        access_key: process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY,
        query: 'New York'
    }

    axios.get('http://api.weatherstack.com/current', {params})
        .then(response => {
            const apiResponse = response.data;
            console.log(response)
            console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.location.name} is ${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`);
            setWeather(apiResponse)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>Temperature in Medellin: {weather.current.temperature}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';      
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And the error:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 105,
    "type": "https_access_restricted",
    "info": "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use https and the same error

Comment: so, you definitely get the error when you use http instead of https? I take it you're on the free plan then

Comment: pretty pointless (free) API - if your webpage is HTTPS, you can't use it - have you tried making the request from *your* server instead

Comment: No no, i use http and throw me that error, and if i try to use https same error

Comment: so, you're on the free plan - which would give an error with https - is your web page http or https?

Comment: It is http, localhost

Comment: hmm, I wonder the API doesn't like `http://localhost/` for some reason - have you tried making the request using curl or something similar ... I see a lot of people talk about "postman" too